Bounds on growth of Gröbner bases
Let $I$ be an ideal with $k$ generators i.e. $I = \langle f_1, \dots, f_k\rangle$ where $f_1, \dots, f_k \in k[x_1, \dots, x_n]$ and fix a monomial ordering.
I am interested in what happens to the size $s$ of the reduced Gröbner basis $G$ of $I$ if we add a new generator $f_{k+1}$. If $\overline{f_{k+1}}^G = 0$ the size $s$ does not change, if $f_{k+1}=1$ the size will drop to $s=1$ because $I=\langle1\rangle$. Since the process of adding new elements defines an ascending chains of ideals it is also true that the size doesn't change at some point.

Is there an upper limit on how much the size of the reduced Gröbner basis can increase in general?

I am interested in examples like this. Where we have a differential operator like
$$\partial = u\frac{\partial}{\partial x} + v\frac{\partial}{\partial y} + x\frac{\partial}{\partial u} + (y-1)\frac{\partial}{\partial v}$$
and a polynomial
$$ q = x^2 + y^2-1$$
and study the ideals
$$ I_k = \langle \partial^l q \,|\, l \le k\rangle.$$
This example is derived from a simple pendulum.
The sizes of the reduced Gröbner basis with fixed grevlex ordering are ($k\to \# G$)
$$0\to1, 1\to3, 2\to7, 3\to7, 4\to11,$$
at $k=4$ it becomes stationary.
